# Percona tool pt-archiver replicated inconsistent data

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

I have a master slave replication. Here i scheduled pt-archiver  for table dltb which archives on condition `insert_date<date_sub(now(),interval 35 days)` to archive table dltb_archive on master .in master it is working fine when i checked that in slave data looks inconsistent . Still i can see older that 35 days in main table.Any one please let me know whats the issue here .

1 . Im using MIXED binlog format in both master and slave.

2 . `pt-archiver --source h=localhost,u=root,p=*****,D=dltbdb,t=dltb --dest h=localhost,u=root,p=******,D=dltbdb,t=dltb_archive --where "insert_date < date_sub(now(),interval 35 day)" --bulk-insert --bulk-delete --limit=5000 --progress 50000`

3 . Here is the delete query of pt-archiver which i found from slow log .

```
DELETE FROM dltbdb.dltb WHERE (((`dl_id` >= '0000AAAAAAAAA2D775804BC6441B8941'))) AND (((`dl_id` <= 'AAAAAAAAAAA5661BDD6EA10A19DD47A4'))) AND (insert_date < date_sub(now(),interval 35 day)) LIMIT 5000;
```

Here dl_id is  varchar(64)  PRIMARY KEY

Comment: The libraries to replicate changes in slaves rely on binlog_format=STATEMENT

Would this cause a problem in your set up or can you try that? I think you can reset that per session.

Comment: Thanks lorraine for the update . As delete query is on limit  im unable to set it to STATEMENT. So issues here is pt-archiver  is not deleting the records completely on main table from slave .for some date.few records are there in main and few are in archive .

Comment: OK to get engineer attention and (possibly) file a bug it might be best I encourage you to the Percona Forum (open source software forums). I am happy to update the SO post with the resolution. 
https://percona.com/forums 
Assuming no one else has an answer for you...

Comment: Have you examined the relay logs of the slaves to ensure that the DELETE statement has indeed been replicated? If you do NOT see the SQL in the slave relay logs, then you have a different issue. Any replication filters? If you DO see the SQL in the slave relay logs, is it the same SQL? Did the SQL generate an error when executed on the slave? Does replication break when you run pt-archiver?